# Reading excel data in selenium with testNG

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am new to Selenium and still learning. I am trying to write a program in TestNG with two tests to read data from excel and to write, using Apache POI. I have one XLS and one XLSX file in the same folder and trying to use both the files. I am looking to configure path and name of the excels in testng.xml. When I executed my first test to read data, the sheet name is  being read as xml. Below is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<parameter name="filePath" value="C:\\Technologies\\Selenium\\WebDriver\\DataFiles\\ExcelFiles"></parameter>
  <test name="Xlsx">
  <parameter name="fileName" value="12142015_sx.xlsx"></parameter>
  <parameter name="sheetName" value="xlsx_1"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="handlefiles.handleExcel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Xls">
  <parameter name="fileName" value="12142015_s.xls"></parameter>
  <parameter name="sheetName" value="xls_1"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="handlefiles.handleExcel"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Below is java class code.

```
package handlefiles;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class handleExcel {

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"filePath", "fileName", "sheetName"})
    public void readExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException{
        // set the file path
        File eFile = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
        //print the file path
        System.out.println("File is at: "+eFile);

        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(eFile);
        Workbook wb = null;

        // Read and publish extension
        String extensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        System.out.println("File type is: "+extensionName);

        //Read the file
        if(extensionName.equalsIgnoreCase(".xlsx")){
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        }else if(extensionName.equalsIgnoreCase(".xls")){
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        }
        //Read the sheet name
        Sheet wbSheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        System.out.println("Sheet Name is: "+wbSheet);

    }

  @Test(priority=1)
  public void readData(Sheet wbSheet) {

    // Get the row count
            int rowCount = wbSheet.getLastRowNum() - wbSheet.getFirstRowNum();

            // print data from excel
            for (int i=0; i<rowCount-1; i++){
                Row row = wbSheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j=0; j<row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
                    System.out.println(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"||");
                }
            }
  }
}
```

When I run this in eclipse, I see below exception-

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:112)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:300)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:400)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:381)
    at handlefiles.handleExcel.readExcel(handleExcel.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:400)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure your .xls file contains pre 2007 excel content?

Comment: Here is the file type from properties - Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stack trace POI thinks you are attempting to open an XLSX file using POI's XLS code (not XLSX code). Perhaps the file extension is wrong for that file is ".xls" but should be ".xlsx" or the file is corrupted, etc. (or maybe you've found a bug).

I suggest using POI's [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) instead:

> Factory for creating the appropriate kind of Workbook (be it
>   [`HSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) or [`XSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html)), by auto-detecting from the supplied
>   input.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following IF Condition and

```
if(extensionName.equalsIgnoreCase(".xlsx")){
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        }else if(extensionName.equalsIgnoreCase(".xls")){
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        }
```

Add this piece of code

```
 wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
```

I used in past and I never told which extension I am using.

Comment: I tried this. The exception has changed but the sheet name is still being read as XML. Below is the testNG trace-
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method readData requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
Console shows as below.
Sheet Name is: Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Sheet Name is: Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml

Comment: @Naresh, I see that you've accepted this answer but your comment leads me to think this did not answer your question. Did you by chance accept the wrong answer? Thanks.

Comment: @mfulton26 thanks for noticing. It might have accidentally happened, not intentional. I have corrected it.